# PLAY_SESSION expiry not changable

Tags: playframework, session-cookies

The file application.conf contains the following lines

```
session.maxAge=7d
application.session.maxAge=7d
```

But the PLAY_SESSION cookie has an expiry time of about 16 minutes after creation.

How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be necessary to do

```
play clean compile
```

in order to change this time.

Then it works.